# ADB detects android device, but missing in Flutter devices

Tags: android, flutter

When I connect my android device (with USB debugging enabled), I am unable to see it with `flutter devices`, but ADB is able to detect it.

I am not sure what logs to share but these are the results.

```
List of devices attached
6783e74c        device
```

And for flutter:

```
3 connected devices:

Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.105
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.44
```

Note: I am not using any Android emulator on my computer, but I don't see why that would be required with a physical device.